# How to update value of particular key inside an Array of Dictionary on tableView DidSelect?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, nsmutablearray

Below mentioned is my array and I have added these dictionaries to NSMutableArray. I want to change the `order_product_type`'s value from Delivery to Pickup when I tap on cell in tableView.

```
({
    name = "Colgate Cibaca";
    "order_product_type" = DELIVERY;
    productTotal = "30.00";
    "product_id" = 32;
    quantity = 1;
},{
    name = "Lays Classic Salted";
    "order_product_type" = DELIVERY;
    productTotal = "20.00";
    "product_id" = 33;
    quantity = 1;
})
```

Kindly help me with code.

Comment: Can you show us some code of what you've got so far?

Comment: What if `order_product_type` is already `Pickup` for tapped cell

Comment: That wont be pickup! I have to make it pickup! after tapping it

Comment: Till now I have done nothing in code, I have just filled my tableView With values from array

Answer (score 3):

you can try this one
var arr = [dict1 , dict2] . In didSelect

```
var dictt = arr[indexpath.item] 
dictt["order_product_type"] = "picked";
arr.remove(at: indexpath.item);
arr.insert(dictt, at: indexpath.item);
```

Answer (score 0):

It helped

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let dataObject = productArray[indexPath.row] as? NSDictionary

    DataDict = [
        "name"                     :   (dataObject?["name"] as? String)!,
        "productTotal"             :   (dataObject?["productTotal"] as? String)!,
        "quantity"                 :   (dataObject?["quantity"] as? Int)!,
        "product_id"               :   (dataObject?["product_id"] as? Int)!,
        "order_product_type"       :   "PICKUP"
    ]
    productArray.replaceObject(at: indexPath.row, with: DataDict)
    print(productArray)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let dataObject = productArray[indexPath.row] as? NSDictionary

        DataDict = [
            "name"                     :   (dataObject?["name"] as? String)!,
            "productTotal"             :   (dataObject?["productTotal"] as? String)!,
            "quantity"                 :   (dataObject?["quantity"] as? Int)!,
            "product_id"               :   (dataObject?["product_id"] as? Int)!,
            "order_product_type"       :   "DELIVERY"
        ]
        productArray.replaceObject(at: indexPath.row, with: DataDict)
        print(productArray)
    }
```

Comment: `(dataObject?["name"] as? String)!` Please learn Optionals. Don't do this kind of nonsense.

Comment: @EricAya would you mind telling whats non sense in this?

Comment: @NiravD Did u read what's written on the top? I have clearly written "it helped". I answered for my own query. So first read then comment. 
If it wouldn't be the answer I would have posted it in question.

Comment: @RajatAttri From your question comment you have added I haven't try anything and then you post answer suddenly thats why I added comment also I'm suggested doesn't down voted your answer, as of now you saying it is solution that you are using i'm deleting my comment also as `Eric` suggested you need to really learn about optional

Comment: @NiravD Till that time I didn't use anything, then ideas keep juggling inside mind, If I am wrong somewhere then I think you can guide, what do I need to learn where am I lacking in optionals? Kindly tell me so that I can rectify them. Thanks in advance

Comment: @RajatAttri I get that this is your answer thats why I deleted my comment, also Eric already told you that you are wrapping optional value in a horrible way, One more thing is that to make changes in single key you are making whole new dictionary and that is not good check  Praddeep's answer you need to extract dictionary make changes with it and set it back that changed dictionary in array

Comment: @NiravD Thanks. I will read about optionals first. :) Thanks a lot